# QR Decomposition when u3 is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to find decomposition for a matrix.

I am using Gram Schmidt.

$ A =  \begin{bmatrix}1&1&7\\1&2&8\\1&3&9\end{bmatrix}$

I am able to find $ u_1 ,u_2, e_1, e_2 $

$ u_3 = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\end{bmatrix} $

How do i proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

This means the third column of $A$ is dependent on the other 2.

If the question does not ask you to find the full QR decomposition, then you can use the current $3\times 2$ matrix $Q$ and a $2\times 2$ matrix $R$. This is the reduced QR decomposition.

If you need a full QR decomposition, then choose a vector that is probably not dependent on the first 2 columns of $A$ or the first two $u$'s to continue. For example, $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: It says reduced QR decomposition

Comment: Then you can just use the current $u_1,u_2$ to form the $3 \times 2$ matrix $Q$ and then the $2\times 2$ matrix $R$ using the coefficients you computed the two vectors.